# Showing injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, functions

I'm trying to prove that the following function is injective:

$$h(x) = \{y\in \mathbb{Q}\| y<x\}$$

I think I should use the fact that the rational number are dense, but I'm not sure where to start....

Comment: Indeed you are correct that this is what you need to use. Start by recalling the definition of injectivity: If $x\neq y$ you want to show that $h(x)\neq h(y)$.

Comment: Is this really a set-valued function? What is the domain of the function? You know about Dedekind cuts?

Comment: It seems I forgot to to properly define my function.. $h:\mathbb{R} -> P(\mathbb{Q})$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: to show a function is injective, you need to show $\forall a,b\in \Bbb Q$, $\space f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$